# Moving directories with subdirectories using `moveSync` from `fs-extra`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fs

I have 2 paths:

`app/consultants/pages/assignments`
`app/consultants/pages/consultants`

Both paths contain subdirectories and files.

I created a reduce function that returns an array of objects with the following structure:

```
[{
  model: 'consultants',
  subModel: 'assignments',
  path: '/app/consultants/pages/assignments'
}

{
  model: 'consultants',
  path: '/app/consultants/pages/consultants'
}]
```

Then I loop through this array and try to move the directory and all its directories and files:

```
getAllPagesDirs(appDir).forEach((pages, index) => {
        if (pages.subModel) {
          fs.moveSync(pages.path, path.join(path.resolve("pages"), pages.model, pages.subModel))
        } else {
          fs.moveSync(pages.path, path.join(path.resolve("pages"), pages.model))
        }
})
```

I'm trying to move the directories to the following with all its files:
`/pages/consultants/[consultantSubdirectory]`
&
`/pages/consultants/assignments/[assignmentsSubdirectory]`

What's currently happening:

I get an error: `dest already exists.` And only the assignments sub directory gets moved.

Edit: I'm using `fs-extra`, but have no issue with using node's `fs` module.

Comment: there is no `fs.move` or `fs.moveSync` in node's `fs` module ... What library are you using?

Comment: @derpirscher I should of added that I'm using `fs-extra`, but I don't mind using node's `fs` module.

Comment: If you look at the docs of [`moveSync`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move-sync.md) from the fs-extra module, it has an optional `options` parameter, which allows you to set `overwrite: boolean`

Comment: @derpirscher yup, but that overwrites everything. Meaning the `assignments` directory will get overwritten since it is moved first.

Comment: Well, then what are you trying to achieve? Merging directories? Move only files that don't exist in the target? If you want that, you probably will have to do that yourself, ie create a list of all directories/files in the source and check if the respective target exists or not ...

Comment: @derpirscher correct. trying to merge directories.